# Javascript: Writing a loop to check when a button is available to click

Tags: javascript, button

I am currently stuck....
I'm writing a simple javascript to refresh a page and check and see if a particular button is available for clicking. When it does become available I would like the script to also click the button.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp

Comment: @Bug , still having a hard time with that. Would it be a good idea to do the click within an if statement so that there is not any meaningless clicking

Comment: What would the if statement be asking? You need to be more descriptive in your question

Comment: The if statement would be asking if the button is available to click(Y/N) then run this code (Y) click the button, (N) Refresh the page